# Adding parameterized predefined query to datagridview

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

For the life of me, I haven't been able to find this anywhere (other than solutions that exclude using the tableAdapter....

I have a simple setup. I have a datagridview. I have a tableadapter that is bound to the datagridview. This all works marvelously, but brings in the entire table. On the tableadapter itself, I have created a query called "nonServers" which returns the data I want.

So my question is, how can i bind the results of the tableadapter's QUERY to the datagridview, rather than the full results? When I try to add the query, it adds a button up top to trigger the query (as it's meant to do). But this is not what I want - i want the initial value to be the results of the query only.

any help appreciated, i reckon it's probably embarassingly simple

Answer (score 0):

You're under some misconceptions.  Firstly, your grid is not bound to a table adapter.  The adapter is just a means to move data back and forth between the database and the application.  The data is stored in the application a `DataTable` that is part of a `DataSet`.  That's what your grid is bound to.

The default query for each table adapter is a `SELECT *` with no `WHERE` clause, so all columns and all rows.  The table adapter has two methods - `Fill` and `GetData` - that execute that query.  `Fill` will populate an existing `DataTable`, which will probably be part of a `DataSet`, while `GetData` creates and returns a new, standalone `DataTable`.

When you add a new query with a `WHERE` clause to filter, you are prompted to name the new methods that will execute that query.  They are named `FillBy` and `GetDataBy` by default and you're supposed to append a meaningful suffix to that, e.g. if you were to filter by a `ParentId` column then you'd name the methods `FillByParentId` and `GetDataByParentId`.  I'm not sure what exactly your query looks like but you might go with `FillWithNonServers` and `GetDataWithNonSevers`.

If you drag a table from the Data Sources window onto your form then that will add a bunch of controls and components by default and it will also generate some code, including a call to the `Fill` method of the appropriate table adapter to the `Load` event handler.  In your case, you simply have to change that `Fill` call to a call to your new method and it will then invoke your custom query instead of the default.